# Scrollbar is not appearing

Tags: java, swing

I have added some code for scrollbar which I got from questions asked by some other people on stackoverflow but I am not getting any scrollbar added to my JTextArea. I want to add scrollbar to JTextArea area2 in f2 frame.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
public class TextAreaExample implements ActionListener {
    JFrame f1 = new JFrame("INPUT WINDOW");
    JFrame f2 = new JFrame("FILE DATA OUTPUT");
    JTextArea area1;
    JTextArea area2;
    JButton b;
    TextAreaExample() {
        area1 = new JTextArea();
        area2 = new JTextArea();
        JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane (area2, JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS, JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
        b = new JButton("click Me");
        b.setBounds(100, 95, 80, 30);
        f1.add(b);

        area1.setBounds(10, 30, 200, 60);
        area2.setBounds(5, 5, 480, 480);
        f1.add(area1);
        f2.add(area2);
        f2.add(scroll);
        f1.setSize(300,140);
        f2.setSize(510, 510);  
        f1.setLayout(null);
        f2.setLayout(null);
        f1.setVisible(true);
        f2.setVisible(true);
        b.addActionListener(this);
        f1.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f2.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if(e.getSource() == b) {
            String s1 = area1.getText();

            String s2 = "";
            try {
                FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream(s1);
                BufferedInputStream bin = new BufferedInputStream(fin);
                int i;
                while((i = bin.read()) != -1) {
                     s2 = s2 + (char)i;
                }
                bin.close();
                fin.close();
            }catch(Exception a) {
                System.out.println(a);
            }
            area2.setText(s2);
        }
    }
    public static void main(String args[]) {  
        new TextAreaExample();

    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
    JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane (area2, JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS, JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
    b = new JButton("click Me");
    b.setBounds(100, 95, 80, 30);
    f1.add(b);

    area1.setBounds(10, 30, 200, 60);
    area2.setBounds(5, 5, 480, 480);
    f1.add(area1);
    f2.add(area2);
```

First you create a JScrollPane using the JTextArea as a parameter, which is correct.

But then you add the text area to the frame, which is incorrect. Swing components can only have a single parent so the text area is removed from the scroll pane.

The scroll pane must be added to the frame.

```
f1.add(scroll);
```

Also, get rid of all the null layouts and setBounds() statements. Swing was designed to be used with layout managers. Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Layout Manager](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) for more information and examples to get your started.

Now when you create the text area you can use:

```
JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea(5, 20);
```

to suggest the original size for the text area. Scrollbars will then appear when more than 5 lines of data is added.